# WebGL2 texImage2D 16-bit then readPixels 16-bit problem

Tags: javascript, image-processing, opengl-es, webgl, webgl2

Is it possible to create a 16-bit 2d texture image and retrieve the original 16-bit values using readPixels?

I made a jsfiddle where I input and draw a green gradient in 16-bit pixels.
I then use readPixels which returns a bunch of [0,0,0,65535] then the next unique value I get is [0,257,0,65535].

I thought this was working properly in full 16-bit until I tested more closely :(  Is it possible to get the exact original 16-bit data (not rounded to 8-bit) using getPixels?

https://jsfiddle.net/mortac8/b23cnrxt/5/

```
// image data
var w = 64;
var h = 64;
var size = w * h * 4;
var img = new Uint16Array(size); // need Uint16Array
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i += 4) {
    img[i + 0] = 0; // r
    img[i + 1] = i; // g
    img[i + 2] = 0; // b
    img[i + 3] = 65535; // a
}
// draw
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
    0, // mip level
    gl.RGBA16UI, // internal format -> gl.RGBA16UI
    w, h, // width and height
    0, // border
    gl.RGBA_INTEGER, //format -> gm.RGBA_INTEGER
    gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, // type -> gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT
    img // texture data
);
```

This gives me green values like a bunch of 0, then a bunch of 257, then a bunch of 514...

```
let pix = new Uint16Array(w*h*4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, pix);
```

This gives me all 0s

```
let pix = new Uint16Array(w*h*4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gl.RGBA_INTEGER, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, pix);
```

```js
// image data
var w = 64;
var h = 64;
var size = w * h * 4;
var img = new Uint16Array(size); // need Uint16Array
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i += 4) {
    img[i + 0] = 0; // r
    img[i + 1] = i; // g
    img[i + 2] = 0; // b
    img[i + 3] = 65535; // a
}

// program
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

var program = gl.createProgram();
//var color_buffer_float_16ui = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float'); // add for 16-bit

// texture
var tex = gl.createTexture(); // create empty texture
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
    0, // mip level
    gl.RGBA16UI, // internal format -> gl.RGBA16UI
    w, h, // width and height
    0, // border
    gl.RGBA_INTEGER, //format -> gm.RGBA_INTEGER
    gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, // type -> gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT
    img // texture data
);
console.log("ORIGINAL IMAGE:");
console.log(img);

// buffer
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var bufferData =  new Float32Array([
    -1, -1,
    1, -1,
    1, 1,               
    1, 1,
    -1, 1,
    -1, -1
]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// shaders
program.vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(program.vs, `#version 300 es
  in vec4 vertex; // incoming pixel input?
  out vec2 pixelCoordinate; // variable used to pass position to fragment shader
  void main(){
     gl_Position = vertex;  // set pixel output position to incoming position (pass through)
     pixelCoordinate = vertex.xy*0.5+0.5; // set coordinate for fragment shader
  }
`);

program.fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(program.fs, `#version 300 es
  precision highp float; // ?
  uniform highp usampler2D tex; // ?
  in vec2 pixelCoordinate; // receive pixel position from vertex shader
  out vec4 fooColor;
  void main() {
     uvec4 unsignedIntValues = texture(tex, pixelCoordinate);
     vec4 floatValues0To65535 = vec4(unsignedIntValues);
     vec4 colorValues0To1 = floatValues0To65535 / 65535.0;
     fooColor = colorValues0To1;
  }
`);

gl.compileShader(program.vs);
checkCompileError(program.vs);
gl.compileShader(program.fs);
checkCompileError(program.fs);

function checkCompileError(s) {
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(s, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
   console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(s));
  }
}

gl.attachShader(program,program.vs);
gl.attachShader(program,program.fs);

gl.deleteShader(program.vs);
gl.deleteShader(program.fs);

// program
gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertex");
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // execute program

let pix = new Uint16Array(size);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, pix);
console.log("READPIXELS:");
console.log(pix);
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: I would be way more useful if you put your code in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Also, have you bothered to check the JavaScript console? The code you posted would get a WebGL error.

Comment: I added a snippet.  Thanks for the tip.  I am still not familiar with all the stackoverflow capabilities.  I was hoping the default framebuffer could return 16-bit values.  The main application I'm working on was designed based on some flawed assumptions by me.

Comment: In response to your comments below, Drawing with a texture is covered [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). drawing in 2D with translation and scale is covered both [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html). You'd need to pass in your 16 bit texture via a `usampler2D`, set the filtering to `NEAREST` since integer texture can not be filtered, and then do some math to get the 16 bit unsigned int values to go from 0 to 1 in the shader on output.

Comment: Yes I have seen your tutorials.  They are awesome!  My problem comes in when I try to zoom/pan (scale/translate) my image.  I need to be able to zoom/pan and contrast enhance each pixel individually.  I was hoping to use the webgl2 canvas to mirror my 2d canvas' scales and translates then grab the original 16bit data from it to do my pixel modifications which are drawn to my 2d canvas.  Originally I wrote what I call a 'pixelMapper' image (where rgb value maps to pixel location on the image) to lookup values in the orig 16bit array.  I'm currently leaning towards just using that (all '2d').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that jsfiddle you're drawing to the default framebuffer and reading back from that. The default framebuffer is RGBA8, which is why you get truncation.

I'm sort of surprised that `gl.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, pix);` is allowed on your system! Usually it'd be only RGBA+UNSIGNED_BYTE.

If you attach the RGBA16UI texture to a framebuffer, and readPixels from that directly, you can get back the original data untruncated: https://jsfiddle.net/3u2tvqe6/

Worth noting that WebGL 2 doesn't guarantee that you can use the RGBA+UNSIGNED_SHORT with RGBA16UI. For unsigned-int-type textures, the only guaranteed readPixels format is *RGBA+UNSIGNED_INT*! This is specified on pages 191 and 193 of the GLES spec: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Is it possible to scale and translate this "non-default" framebuffer?  I had been doing this scale & translate in my shaders.  My end goal is to have a 16-bit representation of my data on a webgl2 canvas which pans/zooms in sync with an 8-bit image on a 2d canvas.  The 16-bit data is used for calculations (ex: contrast enhancement) that result in 8-bit pixels for the 2d canvas.

Comment: In other words, how do I draw this to the screen...or do a scale or translate on it?

Comment: To draw it to the screen, you need to use a shader to (texture) sample from the RGBA16UI texture object's data, and choose how to output that to default framebuffer `null` to draw to the RGBA8 canvas backbuffer by outputting [0.0, 1.0] from the fragment shader.